# Antd design - Heap out of memory - webpacker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, antd, webpacker, apache-mina

I am using rails gem `mina` for deploying my `RubyonRails & React` application into  production

added `antd npm  package` and deployed. so far no issue

when I try to import something from `antd`  eg:

```
import { Icon, List } from 'antd'
```

Below issue is coming

```
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
        1: node::Abort() [/usr/bin/node]
        2: 0x8cd14c [/usr/bin/node]
        3: v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(char const*, bool) [/usr/bin/node]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of node, webpack-dev-server are you running? Some older versions of webpack-dev-server had a memory leak

You might want to specifically allow the V8 engine more RAM with something like this :

```sh
node --max-old-space-size=4096 yourFile.js
```

or in your package.json if you're using create-react-app :

```
"start": "react-scripts --max_old_space_size=4096 start"
```

(I put 4096 for 4GB of RAM but you can go higher if needed obviously).

Comment: what is yourFile.js
 in production

Comment: @ramamoorthy_villi : it's your entry file. I don't know what you're actually using so I put two different ways to actually increase the allowed RAM to the V8 engine.